# Rotations using quaternions and scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation for 6 degree of freedom simulation

Tags: python, scipy, rotation, physics, rotational-matrices

I am writing a simple simulator for a remotely operated underwater vehicle (ROV). I want to use [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.html) implementation of quaternions instead of my previous approach based on constructing the rotation matrices myself using trigonometric functions like explained at [Wiki rotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#General_3D_rotations).

My initial problem (solved): Clearly, I am getting confused somewhere - the code below appears to work at first, but after a few transformations rotations no longer occur around the body axes. I don't yet fully understand what's going on but it appears like some kind of accumulation of errors. Any help in getting this sorted out would be much appreciated.

My current problem: the yaw rotation happens around the global z axis but the other two around the vehicle x and y axes. Any idea how to make this consistent?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation

class RovTemp(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # Main part - rotation matrix around the the global coordinate system axes.
        self.vehicleAxes = np.eye(3)
        # Current roll, pitch, yaw
        self.rotation_angles = np.zeros(3)
        # Unit vectors along the vehicle x, y, z axes unpacked from the aggregate
        # array for ease of use.
        self.iHat, self.jHat, self.kHat = self.getCoordSystem()

    def getCoordSystem(self):
        # iHat, jHat, kHat
        return self.vehicleAxes.T

    def computeRollPitchYaw(self):
        # Compute the global roll, pitch, and yaw angles
        roll = np.arctan2(self.kHat[1], self.kHat[2])
        pitch = np.arctan2(-self.kHat[0], np.sqrt(self.kHat[1]**2 + self.kHat[2]**2))
        yaw = np.arctan2(self.jHat[0], self.iHat[0])
        return np.array([roll, pitch, yaw])

    def updateMovingCoordSystem(self, rotation_angles):
        # Compute the change in the rotation angles compared to the previous time step.
        # dRotAngles = rotation_angles - self.rotation_angles
        # Store the current orientation.
        self.rotation_angles = rotation_angles
        # Create quaternion from rotation angles from (roll pitch yaw)
        self.vehicleAxes = Rotation.from_euler('xyz', rotation_angles, degrees=False).as_matrix()
        # Extract the new coordinate system vectors
        self.iHat, self.jHat, self.kHat = self.getCoordSystem()

rov = RovTemp()

# Plot orientation.
fig  = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("y")
ax.set_zlabel("z")
ax.set_aspect("equal")
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.95, bottom=0.15)
lim = 0.5
ax.set_xlim((-lim, lim))
ax.set_ylim((-lim, lim))
ax.set_zlim((-lim, lim))

def plotCoordSystem(ax, iHat, jHat, kHat, x0=np.zeros(3), ds=0.45, ls="-"):
    x1 = x0 + iHat*ds
    x2 = x0 + jHat*ds
    x3 = x0 + kHat*ds
    lns = ax.plot([x0[0], x1[0]], [x0[1], x1[1]], [x0[2], x1[2]], "r", ls=ls, lw=2)
    lns += ax.plot([x0[0], x2[0]], [x0[1], x2[1]], [x0[2], x2[2]], "g", ls=ls, lw=2)
    lns += ax.plot([x0[0], x3[0]], [x0[1], x3[1]], [x0[2], x3[2]], "b", ls=ls, lw=2)
    return lns

# Plot twice - one plot will be updated, the other one will stay as reference.
plotCoordSystem(ax, rov.iHat, rov.jHat, rov.kHat, ls="--")
lns = plotCoordSystem(ax, rov.iHat, rov.jHat, rov.kHat)

sldr_ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.15, 0.01, 0.7, 0.025])
sldr_ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.15, 0.05, 0.7, 0.025])
sldr_ax3 = fig.add_axes([0.15, 0.09, 0.7, 0.025])
sldrLim = 180
sldr1 = Slider(sldr_ax1, 'phi', -sldrLim, sldrLim, valinit=0, valfmt="%.1f deg")
sldr2 = Slider(sldr_ax2, 'theta', -sldrLim, sldrLim, valinit=0, valfmt="%.1f deg")
sldr3 = Slider(sldr_ax3, 'psi', -sldrLim, sldrLim, valinit=0, valfmt="%.1f deg")

def onChanged(val):
    global rov, lns, ax
    angles = np.array([sldr1.val, sldr2.val, sldr3.val])/180.*np.pi
    rov.updateMovingCoordSystem(angles)
    for l in lns:
        l.remove()
    lns = plotCoordSystem(ax, rov.iHat, rov.jHat, rov.kHat)
    ax.set_title(
        "roll, pitch, yaw = " +", ".join(['{:.1f} deg'.format(v) for v in rov.computeRollPitchYaw()/np.pi*180.]))
    return lns

sldr1.on_changed(onChanged)
sldr2.on_changed(onChanged)
sldr3.on_changed(onChanged)

plt.show()
```

[image: Specified rotation angles (sliders) are not the same as what I calculate later (figure title).]

Comment: "but after a few transformations rotations no longer occur around the body axes" Are you saying that you intend for this to use intrinsic rotation angles? To use intrinsic rotation angles, you can do that by `Rotation.from_euler('XYZ', rotation_angles, degrees=False)`

Comment: Note that converting from Euler angles to quaternions to a rotation matrix is unnecessary. You can directly do `Rotation.from_euler(...).as_matrix()`. Similarly, doing `rotation_matrix.dot(self.initial_rotation_matrix)` is a no-op, since multiplying any matrix by the identity matrix gives the initial matrix.

Comment: I'm unclear on the specific kind of rotation that's intended. Could you explain in more detail, and possibly draw a picture?

Comment: @NickODell thanks for the comments. I've been working on something else for a while but have found the time to look into this again. I have now worked out an updated version that performs a bit better. One outstanding issue is that the yaw rotation happens around the global z axis but the other two around the vehicle x and y axes. Any idea how to make this consistent? See updated description.